# SCEV pass in LLVM usage for array access pattern

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, arrayaccess

I am trying to find array access pattern in a c code using LLVM. I found that SCEV can be used for this purpose but have not been able to find any sample code for using scev. Any ideas how I can use scev to determine array access pattern.

P.S.: SCEV stands for Scalar Evaluation

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate what you mean by saying "array access pattern". The SCEV pass in LLVM is used for recognizing induction variables in loops ([details here](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#scalar-evolution-scalar-evolution-analysis)), so I'm not sure it's the one you need. In any case, if you find that you do need it, you can find usage examples inside LLVM itself. For example in `./lib/Analysis/DependenceAnalysis.cpp`